# php sort array using the keys of months disregard other key

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [strMachineGroupID] => MC000027
    [strMachineGroup] => 1
    [April-201904_QTY] => 1
    [February-201902_QTY] => 1
    [January-201901_QTY] => 1
    [July-201907_QTY] => 1
    [June-201906_QTY] => 1
    [March-201903_QTY] => 1
    [May-201905_QTY] => 1
    [strMachineGroupIDUE] => MC000027
    [April-201904_UE] => 1.00
    [February-201902_UE] => 1.00
    [January-201901_UE] => 1.00
    [July-201907_UE] => 1.00
    [June-201906_UE] => 1.00
    [March-201903_UE] => 1.00
    [May-201905_UE] => 1.00
)
```

This one my array in my query result. I wanted to sort this array so that the result will be show index in monthly order(january to december).

I want that january ill be next to each other as well as other months.

I tried using:

```
    //     $value = (array)$value;
    //     print_r($value);
    //     print_r(asort($value));
    //     print_r(krsort($value));
    //     print_r(ksort($value));
```

But they did work. Im still working on this one.

Any idea that does this will really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to compare the keys. This callback function will sort keys with a date to the beginning (relying on the fact that those keys have a 6 digit `YYYYMM` string in them) and then sort between dates. Non-date keys are sorted alphabetically.

```
uksort($array, function ($k1, $k2) {
    if (preg_match('/^\w+-(\d{6})_\w+$/', $k1, $m1)) {
        if (preg_match('/^\w+-(\d{6})_\w+$/', $k2, $m2)) {
            // both have dates, sort on that
            return strcmp($m1[1], $m2[1]);
        }
        else {
            // dates sort first
            return -1;
        }
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/^\w+-(\d{6})_\w+$/', $k2, $m2)) {
        // dates sort first
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        // neither is a date, sort alphabetically
        return strcmp($k1, $k2);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [January-201901_UE] => 1
    [January-201901_QTY] => 1
    [February-201902_QTY] => 1
    [February-201902_UE] => 1
    [March-201903_UE] => 1
    [March-201903_QTY] => 1
    [April-201904_UE] => 1
    [April-201904_QTY] => 1
    [May-201905_UE] => 1
    [May-201905_QTY] => 1
    [June-201906_QTY] => 1
    [June-201906_UE] => 1
    [July-201907_UE] => 1
    [July-201907_QTY] => 1
    [strMachineGroup] => 1
    [strMachineGroupID] => MC000027
    [strMachineGroupIDUE] => MC000027 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZA70u)

Comment: @guradio no worries. you can use the demo to fine tune the sorting if this isn't exactly what you need.

Comment: Nice answer. But I suggest to use months' names in regexp directly to avoid mistakes

Comment: @Rulisp that is why I have supplied the demo, so OP can tune it in case the regexp doesn't exactly solve his needs. Without seeing *all* the data, to modify the regexp might be unnecessarily complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, you need to use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function. It allows you to write your own comparator. But what about indexes without month and dates after %monthname%?

Comment: i just need to sort index with the months

Comment: @guradio so, `strMachineGroupId` should preserve its position?

Comment: either preserve or move doesnt matter all I need is that the months be next to each other

Comment: idea appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The below method works by trying to split the keys on a dash.  Then a comparison is made on the second part (index 1) if available, if not a comparison is made with the key.

An example comparison between the keys `July-201906_QTY` and `June-201906_QTY` would break down to a comparison between `201906_QTY` and `201906_QTY` in the uksort.

Numbers will float to the top ordered. The grunt work is done via the spaceship operator.

```
<?php
$data =
[
    'strMachineGroupID' => MC000027,
    'strMachineGroup' => 1,
    'April-201904_QTY' => 1,
    'February-201902_QTY' => 1,
    'January-201901_QTY' => 1,
    'July-201907_QTY' => 1,
    'June-201906_QTY' => 1,
    'March-201903_QTY' => 1,
    'May-201905_QTY' => 1,
    'strMachineGroupIDUE' => MC000027,
    'April-201904_UE' => 1.00,
    'February-201902_UE' => 1.00,
    'January-201901_UE' => 1.00,
    'July-201907_UE' => 1.00,
    'June-201906_UE' => 1.00,
    'March-201903_UE' => 1.00,
    'May-201905_UE' => 1.00
];

uksort($data, function($a, $b) {
    $parts_a = explode('-', $a);
    $parts_b = explode('-', $b);

    return ($parts_a[1] ?? $a) <=> ($parts_b[1] ?? $b);
});

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
'January-201901_QTY' => 1,
'January-201901_UE' => 1.0,
'February-201902_QTY' => 1,
'February-201902_UE' => 1.0,
'March-201903_QTY' => 1,
'March-201903_UE' => 1.0,
'April-201904_QTY' => 1,
'April-201904_UE' => 1.0,
'May-201905_QTY' => 1,
'May-201905_UE' => 1.0,
'June-201906_QTY' => 1,
'June-201906_UE' => 1.0,
'July-201907_QTY' => 1,
'July-201907_UE' => 1.0,
'strMachineGroup' => 1,
'strMachineGroupID' => 'MC000027',
'strMachineGroupIDUE' => 'MC000027',
)
```

Comment: I can break it with a key like `"ze-2010Esd"`, but how does this solution work exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen, I've added a short explanation.  And the solution works well on your example data here.  I'm sure a little tweaking could achieve what you want.  You could post a new question with more sample data using this method, if you have problems.

Comment: Ah, I see now. For some reason I missed the `[1]` instead of `[0]`. No, I'm just playing devil's advocate, which may not apply to OP's use case. Very concise solution.

Comment: @ggorlen forgive me, I confused you with the OP.  I think this is a great clean solution.  And nicer than Nick's, as the order is more consistent for month pairs (not that the OP had any specific requirement).

Comment: I agree, but Nick was first posted and got some upvote momentum. Personally, I favor correctness first, but requirements are rather vague here, so this wins the cleanliness contest for sure. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that isn't reliant on anything but the literal month name at the beginning of the string followed by a dash.

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $months = array_flip(
        ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",  "July",
         "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    );

    if (preg_match("`^([A-Z][a-z]+)-`", $a, $x) && array_key_exists($x[1], $months)) {
        if (preg_match("`^([A-Z][a-z]+)-`", $b, $y) && array_key_exists($y[1], $months)) {
            if ($months[$x[1]] === $months[$y[1]]) {
                return $a > $b;
            }

            return $months[$x[1]] - $months[$y[1]];
        }

        return -1;
    }

    return $a > $b;
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [January-201901_UE] => 1
    [January-201901_QTY] => 1
    [February-201902_QTY] => 1
    [February-201902_UE] => 1
    [March-201903_UE] => 1
    [March-201903_QTY] => 1
    [April-201904_UE] => 1
    [April-201904_QTY] => 1
    [May-201905_UE] => 1
    [May-201905_QTY] => 1
    [June-201906_QTY] => 1
    [June-201906_UE] => 1
    [July-201907_UE] => 1
    [July-201907_QTY] => 1
    [strMachineGroup] => 1
    [strMachineGroupID] => MC000027
    [strMachineGroupIDUE] => MC000027
)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/@ggorlen/OutgoingDecisiveDimension)

Answer (score 0):

asort will sort array by the value. ksrot will sort array by the key (use string sort).If you make the key only has number,you can use ksort to sort it.But you must do something specials for string key strMachineGroup,strMachineGroupID,strMachineGroupIDUE

```
Array
(
    [strMachineGroupID] => MC000027
    [strMachineGroup] => 1
    [201904_QTY] => 1
    [201902_QTY] => 1
    [201901_QTY] => 1
    [201907_QTY] => 1
    [201906_QTY] => 1
    [201903_QTY] => 1
    [201905_QTY] => 1
    [strMachineGroupIDUE] => MC000027
    [201904_UE] => 1.00
    [201902_UE] => 1.00
    [201901_UE] => 1.00
    [201907_UE] => 1.00
    [201906_UE] => 1.00
    [201903_UE] => 1.00
    [201905_UE] => 1.00
)
```